# Puppet custom fact with ruby

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

I am new to ruby and am trying to get a puppet custom fact to work. Here is the code for the custom fact:

```
Facter.add("mounts") do
  confine :osfamily => "RedHat"
  setcode do
    mountlist=""
    #Facter::Core::Execution.exec('/bin/mount | /bin/cut -f3 -d" "')
    #mounts=`/bin/mount`
    mounts = Facter::Core::Execution.exec('/bin/mount')

    mounts.each_line do |line|
      fs=line.match(/^[^\s]+\s+on\s(.+) type.+/).captures
      mountlist=mountlist + fs.to_s + ","
    end
    mountlist
  end
end
```

The idea of the code is to create a custom fact called `mounts`, which can then be used in a manifest for a module. Here is one of the stanzas from the manifest file:

```
if ("/tmp" in $mounts) {
  mount{'tmpfs_mnt':
    name     => "/tmp",
    options  => [ 'nodev','nosuid','noexec' ],
    ensure   => present,
    atboot   => true,
    fstype   => tmpfs,
    remounts => true,
  }
}
```

The custom fact does not appear to get created. Here is the output from one of the puppet nodes when trying to pull this module:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: 'undef' from right operand of 'in' expression is not of a supported type (string, array or hash)

Any help on what corrections are needed to get the custom fact working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SOLVED: The custom fact code is fine, it was the location of the code that was the problem. Once I moved the code from ~/lib/ruby/facter to ~/lib/facter it worked.

Comment: Actually, you should place the fact in `module/lib/facter/`. That will work universally.